# github without local repository

Tags: git, github

I just created an account with github. Can I upload my project without local repository and without local git commandline and without local github desktop?

I am looking for something similar to ftp that can directly upload my project into the online repository.

Any way to do that?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. How can you upload a project that's not stored locally?

Comment: Do you mean upload a project to github without actually using git?

Comment: I use TFS at work. The repository is in a database server. So I don't keep local repository. I would think GitHub is just a "remote repository server" and I do not need to keep local repository on my PC. So I can directly check-in and check-out from GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using git to manage and upload your local files. However, If you really want to you can use the "Upload files" button on github to upload files directly:

[image]

**Note:** you'll have to have at least one file present in your github repo to see this page. If you're creating a project from scratch, and seeing the following page, click the "README" button to create a readme and then you'll have the option of uploading additional files.

[image]

Comment: Anthony, I tried "Upload files" button and it gave "Something went really wrong, and we can’t process that file." Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a Github issue. Either it's a temporary issue with the site, or it's rejecting the file based on its file type. Does it happen with any file? or one file in particular?

Comment: I first tried index.html with failure, and then tried .gitignore and it also failed. If I commit it gave a blank page.

Comment: Does happen in other browers? If its a persistent issue, perhaps something on your local machine/browser is modifying the request to Github. Again, as Schwern mentioned, I'd recommend just using Github with Git as it was intended to be used. Its secure, used by major corporations, and doesn't present any security concerns.

Comment: I got it. It's a browser issue. It works with chrome but not firefox. Thanks a lot for your patience with me:)

Comment: Is this firefox issue going to be fixed? I really don't enjoy having to switch browsers just to upload files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes? Sort of? If you [create a repository](https://github.com/new) with the default README you can then use the web interface to add, upload, and edit files.

But I'm not sure why you would do this. It's not how Github is intended to be used and it will be awkward.

[Github has a desktop application](https://desktop.github.com/) that help you work with Git.

Comment: I want to do this for 2 reasons. 1. I don't want to keep a lot of versions on my local PC. 2. I am using free account that is not private. Git try to set a SSH key to my account with my PC address. Since my account is public I am concerned that my PC could be hacked.

Comment: @Shawn None of that is correct. 1) A Git repository is typically very small, about the same size as the checked out files. Disk space will not be an issue. 2) Signing up for a Github account will not get your PC hacked.

Comment: Thank you Schwern for the knowledge. I appreciate it. I would try to setup git then.