# Cannot upload files for release in Github

Tags: github, release

I want ot create a release for my Github project, but when I try to upload my binary (which is a .zip file) to the release, I get the following error message:

> Something went really wrong, and we can’t process that file.

I get the same error message if I try to upload some other files (e.g. my readme file). What could be wrong?

Comment: I am using Chrome and getting this error. Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: Yes, in dev console I see this error: "Failed to load https://github-production-release-asset-XXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://github.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403." Did you ever resolve @SaurabhJain?

Comment: Works in IE (LOL!)

Comment: yes @FizxMike i did. please check my proposed solution below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check first if this issue persists with all *browser*.

I have seen [this error message before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586246/github-without-local-repository#comment60772094_36586317), where the upload succeeded with Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: Same here. It seems that Github doesn't like Firefox.

Comment: Bug on server or in firefox?

Comment: Anyone know if this is a known bug and if it's likely to be fixed?

Comment: For me it didn't work on Chrome Canary, but worked on Safari

Comment: Chrome Canary served its purpose, now Chrome doesn't work, (see my comment on OP). But IE still works.

Comment: @FizxMike IE!? I usually use it only to download Chrome or Firefox ;)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking it was corporate firewall issues, but it smells like Chrome added some "safety" and broke some infrastructure used by GitHub broswer GUI... they need to re-tool/fix a setting. Most "serious" people are using CI nowadays, so us little people (who just want to throw a draft binary up there to get the ball rolling) don't really matter. (Official response would be something like: "you are doing it wrong - manual releases, seriously?")

Answer (score 14):

For the record in my case this was due to an obvious mistake: I had to authorize a github script in NoScript.

Comment: That's it. Temporarily allowing all scripts in NoScript fixed the problem in Firefox for me. +1

Comment: That's it, for me, allowing "fetch" request by default for "non trusted" sites in NoScript fixed the problem in Firefox for me. +1

Comment: for the record: for me the url to allow in NoScript was `github-production-user-asset-6****df.s3.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 6):

If someone encounters this problem in China, and is using ShadowSocks, try turning ShadowSocks off.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to upload an image file in `png` format on chrome browser but I was getting the  same message.As suggested in one of the answer, I **turned off windows firewall** and it worked.

But my mind was not satisfied and I turned on Windows firewall and **converted that image to** `jpg` **format and it got uploaded**.

But this stubborn mind was not satisfied and told me to upload this in .png format only.God came to my rescue and  accidentally **properties tab** of `png` image  got opened and **at the bottom of tab, it was showing**

> "This file came from another computer and might be blocked".

[image: see the link]

**So I unblocked it and it got uploaded.**

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs during file upload because I was using VPN which doesn't allow file upload hence I disconnected from VPN and then try uploading which work absolutely fine. So my advice to check your firewall/VPN settings as mostly Organization doesn't allow fileupload in GIT due to security concern.

Answer (score 1):

I got that error due to my companies firewall that prevents all file uploads. Might this be the cause of your problems?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on Opera browser(Ubuntu 18.04.1).

Then I realized that my browser does not have permission to access the related(where your files located) partition. I moved the files that I wanted to upload on Github into accessible partition by Opera browser in my HDD, Thus I could be able to upload my files to Github.

It worked like a charm. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

clear your browser's cookies and cache ..after clearing files will be uploaded easily on git without error

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I'm reuploading two zip files to an existing release. One success and another one failed. Tried in both chrome and firefox.

My solution is to use the [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) command-line tool.
I use the below command to edit the existing release and attach files to it.

```
hub release edit --draft=false --attach FILE TAG
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I had to change its prefix from .png to .jpg and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which I solved by disabling my firewall. I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was my anti-virus (AVG) preventing the upload.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Avast antivirus was blocking the `objects-origin.githubusercontent.com` site, and made the upload fail.

After disabling the antivirus, I was able to upload the files.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution.
The problem is not with the browser. You need to take your files from the ZIP Folder and paste them into the desktop.

Then drag the files from the desktop and drop them into Github. (you can drag one by one if you want)

Trust me, it will work!!!

Take care!

Answer (score -3):

Files cannot be uploaded because your network provider doesn't allow, use different network or apply vpn for uploading the files.